# Make zip archives of files in a txt list - with folder structure via Bat File

Tags: windows, batch-file, zip, 7zip

How can i do that. I  tried it with a for loop, but it doesnt work well.

Can someone help me? (and sorry for my english)

Here is the Code:

```
@echo.
@set h=%time:~0,2%
@set m=%time:~3,2%
@set s=%time:~6,2%

@set ARCDATE=%DATE:~6,4%%DATE:~3,2%%DATE:~0,2%
@set LISTE=C:/BatchDateiHotfix/list.txt
@set SAVELOC=C:\Users\gkrobath\Desktop\BatchDateiHotfix\310
@set SITOS=C:\SVN_Check\SITOS_3_10\html
@set SVNUPDATE=C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin\TortoiseProc.exe
@set PACK="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a
rem @set PACK="C:\Program Files\WinRAR\Rar.exe" a -r

@cd %SITOS%

@set /p KUNDE=Kundennamen eingeben ........... 
@echo.
@set /p NMR=TMS/OIS-Nummern eingeben ..... 

@set FILE="%SAVELOC%/%KUNDE%_hotfix_%NMR%_%ARCDATE%.zip"
@set HOTFIX=%PACK% %FILE%

@for /F %%a in (%LISTE%) do (
if not exist %%a goto errors else 
@%HOTFIX% %%a)
```

Hopefully anyone can help me .-)

Comment: we need to see your code before suggesting any thing

Comment: and what is the error you are facing

Comment: So it comes down to the last line: You call your packer with some parameters. Does it work if you call it by hand with the parameters you think your script should pass?

Comment: it doesnt make a zip-file - or sometimes it does, but then it is only one random file from the list in there. No special errors or warnings

Comment: @AlexanderKosube Yes it works when i call it by hand with the parameters

Comment: The ) is a mistake. I deleted it. %KUNDE% and %NMR% are correct. I think it works with single files, but not with the loop.

Comment: Where are you looping? Am I just too blind to see? - All I see is that you pass a filename, which supposedly points to a file with a list of files to be zipped, right? - Are the forward slashes `/` in the filename intentional? I do not remember 7zip requiring them...

Comment: All I see is that you pass a filename, which supposedly points to a file with a list of files to be zipped, right? - YES
Are the forward slashes / in the filename intentional? - YES, they are.

Comment: oh, have posted the wrong code: this part is different @for /F %%a in (%LISTE%) do (
if not exist %%a goto errors else 
@%HOTFIX% %%a)

Answer (score 1):

This syntax should help you, but it will exit the loop on any error where the file doesn't exist.

```
@for /F "delims=" %%a in (%LISTE%) do (
   if not exist "%%~a" (
       goto errors
     ) else (
       @%HOTFIX% "%%~a"
   )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code will exit as soon as %%a value is a file that doesn't exist.  I don't see the ":errors" labels code.

Instead of using `goto errors`, use a function call so that the loop continues.

```
:ErrNotExist
echo.
echo. The following file does not exist:
echo. %~1
echo.
goto:eof
```

Then change your loop code to something like this:

```
@for /F %%a in (%LISTE%) do (
    if not exist %%a (
       CALL:ErrNotExist %%a 
    ) else (
       @%HOTFIX% %%a
    )
)
```

This will at least get you closer to finding out what is happening in your code.

Comment: Error:
7-Zip cannot move the file
rand_hotfix_rand_20131121.zip.tmp1
C:\Users\gkrobath\Desktop\BatchDateiHotfix\randstad/rand_hotfix_rand_20131121.zi
p
Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung
ist falsch.

System error:
Unbekannter Fehler

Comment: Error:
7-Zip can not move the file
rand_hotfix_rand_20131121.zip.tmp1
C: \ Users \ gkrobath \ Desktop \ BatchDateiHotfix \ randstad/rand_hotfix_rand_20131121.zi
p
The syntax for file name, directory name, or volume label
is wrong.

System error:
unknown error

Comment: I do not use 7-Zip, but based on the error text, it looks like it's a system file and is unable to **move** the file to the zip file. Try the options required to copy only.  OR, maybe you've got an error in your path or filename (e.g. extra spaces, wrong slashes, etc.).  It might help to `echo` your `"%HOTFIX%"` & `"%%a"` immediately before you execute them.  Compare the lines that fail to the lines that succeed.